# retrieve unique value from the table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

This is my scenario

- Each State have multiple Zones
- Each Zone have multiple District
- Each District have multiple City
- Each City have multiple House
- In each House multiple officers lives, whose having unique identity

So, now i want to check whether information, which belongs to particular officer with specified designation and specified zone are already in table or not.

I was trying like this

```
SELECT DISTRICT_ID FROM DISTRICT WHERE DISTRICT_ID='(SELECT DISTRICT_ID FROM CITY WHERE CITY_ID='(SELECT CITY_ID FROM CITY_INFO WHERE CITY_PIN=(SELECT CITY_PIN FROM STATION_HOUSE WHERE STATION_ID='(SELECT STATION_ID FROM OFFICER_HISTORY OH,OFFICER O WHERE OH.OFFICER_ID=O.OFFICER_ID AND (O.DESIGN_ID='"+design+"' AND O.STATUS_TYPE='ACTIVE'))'))')' AND ZONE_ID='"+zone+"'
```

Which means, it will show the district id of the particular officer whose status is **ACTIVE** and that belongs to specified zone.

If above query return the information, which means information already exist. Since, there is no data exist related to condition in my table, but I think my sql query is perfect. But, it's too lengthy. If anyone help me to make it short and efficient one, then i'll very much appreciate him/her.

Answer (score 2):

Should do as joining tables and not a series of sub queries.

```
SELECT DISTRICT_ID FROM DISTRICT 
inner join city on district.district_id = city.district_id
inner join city_info on city.city_id = city_info.city_id
inner join station_house on station_house.city_pin = city_info.city_pin
inner join officer_history on officer_history.station_id = station_house.station_id
inner join officer on officer.officer_id = officer_history.officer_id   
    and officer.design_id= design 
    and officer.status_type = 'ACTIVE'
    and officer.zone_id = zone
```

Take care as concatenating SQL text and variables will leave you open to SQL injection attacks, so turn your SQL query into a a parametrised query if it concerns you.

Comment: but, zone_id does not belongs to officer table, it belongs to district table

Comment: when alter it to read, inner join city on district.district_id = city.district_id and district.zone_id = zone

Comment: SELECT DISTRICT_ID FROM DISTRICT 
 inner join city on district.district_id = city.district_id and and district.zone_id = zone
 inner join city_info on city.city_id = city_info.city_id
 inner join station_house on station_house.city_pin = city_info.city_pin
 inner join officer_history on officer_history.station_id = station_house.station_id
 inner join officer on officer.officer_id = officer_history.officer_id  
  and officer.design_id= design 
  and officer.status_type = 'ACTIVE'

Comment: obviously [design] and [zone] are you variable which you deal with as in your question, if you wish

Comment: Since, i don't have data in my table so, i won't be able to check your query. But, later I'll select your answer, if it works perfectly.

Comment: i see.  The important point is you accept the principal/approach behind the answer thats what stackoverflow is answering not writting code for you :-)  But hope it helps